# How to merge into unrelated branch using git?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Hi I am wondering how to merge into unrelated branch.

- I created a project locally.
- Now I want to push that project into **repository: 'A'** under its **branch: 'dev-branch'**.
- I want to completely remove everything currently in **'dev-branch'** and replace it with my local project

how would I do that without updating my local code? Thank you im still trying to learn as much about git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

- a local clone of that repo, checked out at the `dev-branch`
- another folder with your new code (not under git)

You can replace your current working tree with that new code:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git checkout dev-branch

git --work-tree=/path/to/other/folder/with/my/code add .
git commit -m "Replace with new code"

git push -u origin dev-branch
```

Comment: Thank you very much this did exactly what I needed to do

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy but ⚠️**dangerous** way to do that.

1. Make your **local** repository to have a remote **repo 'A'**. (you might want it to be the 'origin')
2. Create a branch that will have the same name as your target branch. (In your case 'dev-branch')
3. Now, execute this dangerous line ⚠️`git push -u -f`⚠️. (it means `remote set as tracking branch and do forced update`)

Note: Please verify on your dev server first.

Comment: This worked as well thank you I gave the accepted answer to the other comment first though because it solved my problem as well and it was first. Thank you though!